# Docker container networking - Kafka Producer

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to produce messages from a container A to a Kafka topic in a container B, but I am facing some weird issues with the networking of these containers. 
Do you have any idea on how I can connect those containers in a proper way?
The problem is that the collector service cannot see the kafka from the other container and cannot add messages to it.
More specifically I have the services below:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ADVERTISED_HOST: zookeeper
      ADVERTISED_PORT: 2181
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      - meetup-net

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      - meetup-net

collector:
    image: collector:v1
    environment:
      - kafka-bootstrap-servers=docker_kafka_1.docker_meetup-net
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - meetup-net
networks:
  meetup-net:
    driver: bridge
```

and on the other side I have the application.conf file

```
streaming {
  window-size = 50
  window-interval = 5

  kafka-bootstrap-servers = ${?kafka-bootstrap-servers}
  kafka-bootstrap-servers = "localhost:9092"

  sink-topic = ${?source-topic}
  sink-topic = "meetup"

  key-value-json-path = ${key-value-json-path}
  key-value-json-path = "./data/keyvalue"

  source-topic-checkpoint-location = ${source-topic-checkpoint-location}
  source-topic-checkpoint-location = "./target/source-topic"

  sink-topic-checkpoint-location = ${sink-topic-checkpoint-location}
  sink-topic-checkpoint-location = "./target/sink-topic"
}

zookeeper.server = ${?zookeeper-server}
zookeeper.server = "localhost:2181"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` correctly.

At the moment `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` means that any client connecting to the broker will get `localhost` as the broker address on which to connect for subsequent requests. 
Unless *the client is running on the broker* (which it isn't here) then you need to change this configuration. For running in a self-contained Docker env this is easy enough:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

Now any client connection should be to `kafka:29092`. This also means that you can connect a client *running on your Docker host* to the Kafka broker which can be useful e.g. when running on a laptop and running a client locally.

[Here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/community-components-only/docker-compose.yml#L22) is a sample Docker Compose showing this in action.

For more details and background, see https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/